# Owner and User in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am facing issue with permission in Linux. I would like to know the difference between User and Owner of a particular file and directory, if its a non root user in linux.
Please help.

Comment: I think you are probably better off asking this question on the superuser network on stackexchange  as it has nothing to do with programming which is what stackoverflow is about

Answer (score 0):

User is the one who has logged in currently. owner is the creator of the file/folder, which is shown when you do a "ls -l".